# Passing arguments while running selenium webdriver for Python

Tags: python, selenium, arguments, webdriver

I am using selenium python webdriver for my python test cases.
I have a python script NowSpots_Traffic.py which I'm trying to run from Ubuntu terminal (something similar to command prompt in windows)

python /home/vijay/Projects/SeleniumScripts/NowSpots_Traffic.py samuel secrete

where samuel and secrete are two arguments which I need to pass to my python script NowSpots_Traffic.py

I followed the instructions found at [Running Tests in Python with Selenium 2 and WebDriver](http://simeonvisser.com/2/running-tests-in-python-with-selenium-2-and-webdriver/)
 section "Multiple browsers and multiple platforms".

But I get the following error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vijay/Projects/SeleniumScripts/NowSpots_Traffic.py", line 43, in <module>
    unittest.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 152, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 161, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 128, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 100, in loadTestsFromName
    parent, obj = obj, getattr(obj, part)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'samuel'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Unittest.main() function uses the arguments you pass in to determine test cases to run. See here: [Test Discovery](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest#test-discovery)

If your script also needs arguments, you will want to remove them from sys.argv before calling

```
unittest.main()
```